# AMPscript - Redirect() combined with Concat?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I've been trying to figure out how to work with passing URL parameters when using `CONCAT(CloudPagesURL(XX),"&=sk",@subscriberKey")` and also 
`CONCAT(CONCAT(CloudPagesURL(XX),"&=sk"),@subscriberKey")`.

I've even tried working with http://www.google.com?sk=@subscriberKey and http://www.google.com?sk=%%=v(@subscriberKey)==%

however, it appears that because when using redirect, the URL is shown inside "" and since it's already within the ampscript code section is doesn't evaluate ampscript variables inside "".

Even breaking it up into:

```
@URL = http://www.google.com?sk=
@variable = @subscriberKey
@finalURL = CONCAT(@url, @variable)
Redirect(@finalURL)
```

didn't work.

Have anybody else experienced this? and know of a workaround?

Comment: Your AMPScript isn't valid.  Is that copied directly from your page?

Comment: These examples may be helpful: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/113971/web-analytics-connector-breaking-custom-unsubscribe-page-when-clicked-within-ema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lots of ways to achieve this -

**Example:1** You can use [CloudPagesURL](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/microsite_and_landing_page_ampscript_functions/cloudpagesurl/#cloudpagesURL) & [Redirect](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/microsite_and_landing_page_ampscript_functions/redirect/#Redirect) `AmpScript` function and pass the additional parameter inside the `CloudPagesURL`.

```
%%[
SET @SubscriberKey = "test@gmail.com"
    IF Not Empty(@SubscriberKey) Then
       Redirect(CloudPagesURL(PassCloudPageID,"sk", @SubscriberKey))
    EndIF
]%%
```

**Example:2** You can use [Redirect](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/microsite_and_landing_page_ampscript_functions/redirect/#Redirect) & [Concat](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/concat/#concat) `AmpScript` function to add the additional parameter in URL.

```
%%[
SET @SubscriberKey = "test@gmail.com"
    IF Not Empty(@SubscriberKey) Then
       Redirect(ConCat('http://www.google.com&sk=',@SubscriberKey))
    EndIF
]%%
```

Comment: Hi Palash - the first example might just do it. Have you tested the second One before ? Because that crashed the site when i tried.

Comment: Yeah, I used many times and just now cross checked; its working like a champ!

Answer (score 3):

I'm using `Concat` and `RedirectTo` for creating links in AMPscript and for me the following code works (Hostname, somevar and paramvalue are read from dataextensions (code not included in my example)):

```
%%[
    Set @link = Concat('https://', @Hostname, '/', LowerCase(@somevar) ,'/some/string/and?param=', @paramvalue)
]%%

<a href="%%=RedirectTo(@link)=%%">%%=v(@link)=%%</a>
```

Comment: Yeah, but redirectTo is designed for emails and works upon clicking. Redirect is for CloudPages and redirects the browser :)

Comment: @KennethWagner Sorry, I read over that detail ;)